# Concatenation: invalid syntax

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
zeroct_pre = 0
total_pre = 10
pct = round((zeroct_pre/float(total_pre))*100,1)
print 'Number of >= 1 pre-submissions: ' + str(zeroct_pre) + ' (' + str(pct) + '%)'
```

But gives this error:

```
  File "count.py", line 4
    print 'Number of >= 1 pre-submissions: ' + str(zeroct_pre) + ' (' + str(pct) + '%)'
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried changing all `'` to `"` but same error. I'm running Python 3.5.1, any thoughts on why? This code was just working and I've made no changes (no whitespace changes etc).

Comment: Python >=3 uses print as a function

Answer (score -1):

In Python 3, print is now a function. You're trying to use the Python 2 syntax for printing.

Take a look at this: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html

You need to add parenthesis:

```
print ('Number of >= 1 pre-submissions: ' + str(zeroct_pre) + ' (' + str(pct) + '%)')
```

Comment: Probable should avoid answer questions like this. It has already been asked **several** times before and has answers.